# Weird syntaxError after electron app packaging : Unexpected token (

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I am currently trying to package my electron app for the first time, and I am encountering a weird bug.

When launching the app.exe, this error message appears :

> Uncaught Exception:
> C:\  ....  \build\main.js:39
> electron_1.app.on("ready", async () => {
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
> at Object.export.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
> at ...

The arrow points at the parenthesis right after `app.on`.

The app is compiled from typescript to js with tsc (not that this would affect the final result I suppose), then packed with

```
electron-packager . testApp --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --electron-version=1.4.3
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I am really stumped by this error.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so turns out the command I was using to package the app was specifying an electron version (unnecessary) different from the one I used. Removing the specific version from the command line fixed it.